# MVC5 ApplicationUser custom properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am trying to get to grips with the new Membership system introduced in ASP.NET MVC 5 and I've come across a small issue which I am pretty sure you will be able to help me with.

I am going based off [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) and have introduced custom properties to ApplicationUser such as Name, Surname, DOB, etc.

However, instead of creating the user, I am trying to update the currently logged in one. I am looking at the controller method which is currently used to change password.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Manage(ManageUserViewModel model)
        {
            string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            bool hasLocalLogin = await IdentityManager.Logins.HasLocalLoginAsync(userId);
            ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = hasLocalLogin;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");

            if (hasLocalLogin)
            {               
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    IdentityResult result = await IdentityManager.Passwords.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserName(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
                    if (result.Success)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = "Your password has been changed." });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddErrors(result);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // User does not have a local password so remove any validation errors caused by a missing OldPassword field
                ModelState state = ModelState["OldPassword"];
                if (state != null)
                {
                    state.Errors.Clear();
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    // Create the local login info and link it to the user
                    IdentityResult result = await IdentityManager.Logins.AddLocalLoginAsync(userId, User.Identity.GetUserName(), model.NewPassword);
                    if (result.Success)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = "Your password has been set." });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddErrors(result);
                    }

            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

How exactly would I go on about updating an ApplicationUser's Surname for example? Do I need to call the DbContext or?

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Explore `IdentityManager.Store.UserManagement` and `IdentityManager.Store.Users`.

```
ApplicationUser cUser = (ApplicationUser) await IdentityManager.Store.Users.FindByNameAsync(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
cUser.Surname = "New Something";
IdentityResult result1 = await IdentityManager.Store.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Above code is an example only. Basically you need to explore the `Store` property of `IdentityManage`.

Comment: +1 You can use CancellationToken.None from System.Threading rather than create one BTW.

Answer (score 3):

When we used the Users object of our database context we ran into other tracking errors. In our application, we would retrieve users as such

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(userId);
```

Edit the properties:

```
user.StorageName = "gooblygook";
//whatever other properties you would like to use
```

And then we would save it with the UserManager in the controller:

```
UserManager.Update(user);
```

This is currently a working solution for us.

Answer (score 2):

Mark the Person object as **virtual** in your ApplicationUser definition. That worked for me.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
```