# Cannot update ASP.NET Core IdentityRole object

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I am trying to update an `IdentityRole` object, but I am getting an `InvalidOperationException` error.

**Code**

```cs
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

    public EditModel(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public IdentityRole IdentityRole { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        IdentityRole = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

        if (IdentityRole == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        try
        {
            await _roleManager.UpdateAsync(IdentityRole); //Error is occurring here.
        }

        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

**Error**

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'IdentityRole' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

Answer (score 3):

I changed my code like this and now it works. When I update the `IdentityRole.Name` property, it also automatically updates the `IdentityRole.NormalizedName` column in the database.

```cs
var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(IdentityRole.Id);
role.Name = IdentityRole.Name;
await _roleManager.UpdateAsync(role);
```

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839881/asp-net-identity-2-0-update-user).