# Updating user data with ApplicationUser class - ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have an Edit page for users, which works fine for GET, but for POST AplicationUser object is not saved in database. I mention that some of the object fields are null, but it's passed to POST method successfully.

I tried to assign a value for each property corresponding to database column in case it's null with if statements, but that haven't solved the problem, no errors either..
I figured out that [Updating user data - ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444022/updating-user-data-asp-net-identity) second answer (JoshdeVries) from this post may be related to my case.

[A photo with the Object in Debugging mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M0pH.jpg)

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Email,Password,ConfirmPassword,Roles,PhoneNumber")] ApplicationUser editUserModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
            var result manager.Update(editUserModel);
            if (!result.Succeeded) // This is false, so Update Failed!
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result.Errors.ToList());
                return View(editUserModel);
            } 
            store.Context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("UsersList");
        }
        return View(editUserModel);
    }
```

And in View 3 input fields like this(I need to fill more fields but these 3 are for test):

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If those are the only three values you've bound to your view, you aren't posting enough information for EF to find the matching entity.

Comment: How to Fix that ? Email address is unique for sure, EF should be able to find it.

Comment: Only if that field is marked as the primary key field. The correct way to "fix" this is to not use data models as view models.

Comment: manager.Update(editUsersModel); will work only with an object of type ApplicationUser. Making another model just to copy each Property of ApplicationUser object to my Model object and making a query for each of the model properties to change value in database, I find it to be bad design.. :)

Comment: "making a query for each of the model properties to change value in database" - I'm not sure what you mean by that. Assuming your view model had your primary key field (say, `ID`), you would do something like `var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ID == model.ID)`, and then update the relevant fields. Regardless, I would assume you just need to add a hidden input field for your primary key field.

Comment: I noticed that when I use if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
     Console.WriteLine(result.Errors.ToList());
     return View(editUserModel);
    } 
    Succeeded is false...

Comment: In short... you need to include ID in your view as a hidden field so it can be posted back to your controller

Comment: Hey Nick.McDermaid, thanks for answer, I get it now, it needs an identifier, I used another syntax to solve this, I updated the Topic. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[P.S.] Solution that I applied so far and it's working fine:**

```
{
        if (editUserModel.UserName == null)
        {
            editUserModel.UserName = editUserModel.Email;
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(editUserModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("UsersList");
        }
        return View(editUserModel);
}
```

For some reason it seems to me that 'UserName' is some kind of Key that is mandatory to indentify the user row.