# Not able to update AspNetUsers Identity with custom properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql

I want to update the AspNetUsers table with custom properties. I want the users to be able to insert address information after registering. With the code, I don't get any errors, and it doesn't update the table. The model and view are created with razor pages.

[The table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fZwS.png) (the nulls are when I try to update the user, and the information below it is when adding address information when registering)

Although, when I let users add address information when registering, it does update the table.The register razor page is created by Identity, and I scaffolded the item and added my custom properties to it.

**Address.cshtml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using bytme.Models;
using bytme.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace bytme.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage
{
    public class AddressModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<UserModel> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<UserModel> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<AddressModel> _logger;

        public AddressModel(
            UserManager<UserModel> userManager,
            SignInManager<UserModel> signInManager,
            ILogger<AddressModel> logger)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        [TempData]
        public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            [Display(Name = "Name")]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Invalid input. Maximum is 100 characters.")]
            public string name { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            [Display(Name = "Surname")]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Invalid input. Maximum is 100 characters.")]
            public string surname { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            [Display(Name = "Street")]
            [StringLength(48, ErrorMessage = "The longest street name in the Netherlands is 48 characters.")]
            public string street { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            [Display(Name = "House Number")]
            [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "The longest house number in the Netherlands is 5 characters.")]
            public string streetnumber { get; set; }

            //[DataType(DataType.Text)]
            //[Display(Name = "House Number Addition", Description = "For example A or II")]
            //[StringLength(6, ErrorMessage = "
            //public string streetnumberadd { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            [Display(Name = "City")]
            [StringLength(28, ErrorMessage = "The longest place name in the Netherlands is 28 characters.")]
            public string city { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
            [Display(Name = "Postal Code")]
            [RegularExpression(@"^[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?[a-zA-Z]{2}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid zip, for example: 1234AB")]
            public string zipcode { get; set; }
        }

        public void OnGet(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(InputModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                // Get the current application user
                var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

                //Update the details
                user.name = model.name;
                user.surname = model.surname;
                user.street = model.street;
                user.streetnumber = model.streetnumber;
                user.city = model.city;
                user.zipcode = model.zipcode;

                // Update user address
                var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("User added their address information successfully.");
            StatusMessage = "Your address information has been added.";

            return RedirectToPage();
        }
    }
}
```

**Address.cshtml**

```
@page
@model AddressModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add Address Information";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@Html.Partial("_StatusMessage", Model.StatusMessage)
<div>
    <h3>Change your account settings</h3>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <partial name="_ManageNav" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h4>@ViewData["Title"]</h4>
                    <form id="address-form" method="post">
                        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Input.name"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Input.name" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Input.name" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Input.surname"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Input.surname" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Input.surname" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Input.street"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Input.street" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Input.street" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Input.streetnumber"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Input.streetnumber" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Input.streetnumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Input.city"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Input.city" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Input.city" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Input.zipcode"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Input.zipcode" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Input.zipcode" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" asp-page-handler="OnPostAsync">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

**Register.cshtml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using bytme.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace bytme.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<UserModel> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<UserModel> _userManager;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<UserModel> userManager,
            SignInManager<UserModel> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            [Display(Name = "Name")]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Invalid input. Maximum is 100 characters.")]
            public string name { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            [Display(Name = "Surname")]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Invalid input. Maximum is 100 characters.")]
            public string surname { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            [Display(Name = "Street")]
            [StringLength(48, ErrorMessage = "The longest street name in the Netherlands is 48 characters.")]
            public string street { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            [Display(Name = "House Number")]
            [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "The longest house number in the Netherlands is 5 characters.")]
            public string streetnumber { get; set; }

            //[DataType(DataType.Text)]
            //[Display(Name = "House Number Addition", Description = "For example A or II")]
            //[StringLength(6, ErrorMessage = "
            //public string streetnumberadd { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            [Display(Name = "City")]
            [StringLength(28, ErrorMessage = "The longest place name in the Netherlands is 28 characters.")]
            public string city { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
            [Display(Name = "Postal Code")]
            [RegularExpression(@"^[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?[a-zA-Z]{2}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid zip, for example: 1234AB")]
            public string zipcode { get; set; }
        }

        public void OnGet(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var user = new UserModel
                {
                    UserName = Input.Email,
                    Email = Input.Email,
                    name = Input.name,
                    surname = Input.surname,
                    street = Input.street,
                    streetnumber = Input.streetnumber,
                    city = Input.city,
                    zipcode = Input.zipcode
                };

                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    // confirmation code + custom URL creation
                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    // mailmessage creation...
                    // ...
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }


    }
}
```

**Register.cshtml**

```
@page
@model RegisterModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
            <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.name"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.surname"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.surname" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.surname" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.street"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.street" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.street" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.streetnumber"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.streetnumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.streetnumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.city"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.city" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.city" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.zipcode"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.zipcode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.zipcode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

**UserModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace bytme.Models
{
    public class UserModel : IdentityUser
    {
        public override string Id { get; set; }
        public override string Email { get; set; }
        public override string UserName { get; set; }
        public override string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public string zipcode { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string street { get; set; }
        public string streetnumber { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your problem and I found out the following. The reason why your table display null values is the fact, that the parameter `model` in your method is always null.

> `public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(InputModel model)`

So you are updating your properties over `user` entity within null values. Binding needs to follow some convention. You have got two options here:

Because you are binding your property `Input`, with `[BindProperty]` attribute where your view is using tag `asp-for="Input.name", ...` over each input type, you might access directly via binded property.

```
//get rid of parameter model, access directly in method body
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {

      user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

      user.name = Input.name;
      user.surname = Input.surname;
      user.street = Input.street;
      user.streetnumber = Input.streetnumber;
      user.city = Input.city;
      user.zipcode = Input.zipcode;

      var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

      return RedirectToPage();

    }
```

or second option - you can use the parameter in your method, but it must follow the naming convention. If you use for each `input` in your view naming like `Input.name, Input.surname, etc.`, the parameter at method needs to be named as well `Input`.

> `public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(InputModel input)` 
>   *Now you are able to access to binded values via parameter (it is ok to use small letter at the begging of the parameter name)* *For more information about binding see this [link](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding)*

If I've done everything, see above, I'm able to update the model correctly *(without null values)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping! Changing model.name etc. to Input.name did the trick! Couldn't thank you enough! <3

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable migrations in order to update the database? may be sharing the log could provide some information. 
I usually don't work with code first, but Identity Framework creates some triggers and stuff that might be interfering with the properties you intend to add. Try adding "nullable" in the properties UserModel.cs, probably the table is expecting a value and when registered is not getting one.
I had a similar problem, but letting identity framework create all it's stuff over my database, solved the issue. Note that my approach was database first!

Comment: I created the database through migrations. I haven't made it nullable, I will try that thanks.