# ASP.NET MVC: Custom identity fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How should I update custom made identity fields in ASP.NET MVC?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string customerName { get; set; }
    public string customer_lastName { get; set; }
    public string customer_phoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string addressType { get; set; }
    public string addressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string addressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string[] location_details { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        
        return userIdentity;            
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

To be more specific, how am I supposed to update fields such as `customerName`,or `customer_lastName` after a value has been inserted in database for that field ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444022/updating-user-data-asp-net-identity